# How to efficiently add a new key to an RDD in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have 2 RDDs formats, the first one is `((provider, currency), value)` where the key is `(provider, currency)` and the second one `(provider, value)` where the key is `provider`.

What I want to do is transform an RDD **A** from the `(provider, value)` format to `((provider, currency), value)`. I have an **B** `((provider, currency), value)` RDD where I'll take the keys. Then I'll use these keys to expand RDD **A** so that every `value` from the `(provider, value)` RDD will repeat itself for every `currency` in the new `((provider, currency), value)` RDD.

How could this be done in an efficient way, without having to collect() the RDDs and loop through them?

For example:

An item from RDD **A** would be:

```
(1773570, 4135.7998046875)
```

then some of the keys from RDD **B** would be

```
[(1773570, 'EUR/USD'), (1773570, 'GBP/USD'), (1773570, 'USD/CAD')]
```

the output RDD should be:

```
[((1773570, 'EUR/USD'), 4135.7998046875), ((1773570, 'GBP/USD'), 4135.7998046875), ((1773570, 'USD/CAD'), 4135.7998046875)]
```

A possible solution would be:

```
def get_keys(rdd):
    return rdd.map(lambda item: (item[0])).collect()

def canonicalize_keys(sc, feature, keys):
    def transform(item, keys):
        return [
            ((item[0], currency_pair), item[1])
                for provider_id, currency_pair in keys
                    if provider_id == item[0]]
    return sc.parallelize(feature
        .map(lambda item: transform(item, keys))
        .reduce(lambda a, b: a + b))
```

Here I get the keys from RDD **B** using `get_keys` and then I use these keys transform RDD **A**. The problem here is that if I have a lot of currency_pairs I get OutOfMemoryErrors from the JVM.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely, do you want the valid provider -> currency pairs to come from (provider, currency) key of the first RDD, and then use this to explode the second RDD so that each (provider, value) is effectively repeated once for each instance of currency?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I will edit the post to make it clearer.

Comment: It's still not very clear. Can you provide an example of input and expected output ?

Comment: I edited the post and added an example

Comment: Updated post with a possible solution that however has memory issues when using it with a larger dataset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: 
Given `Ardd = RDD[(provider, value)]` and `Brdd = RDD[((provider, currency), value)]`, what you want to do is join `Ardd` and `Brdd` such that `newRDD` would be of the form `RDD[((provider, currency), value)]`. Where `value` refers to the value found from `Ardd`.

To do that, what we do is this:

**One Line Solution:**

```
newRDD = Ardd.join(Brdd.map(lambda x: x[0])).map(lambda x: ((x[0], x[1][1]), x[1][0]))
```

**With Step by Step Explanation:**

1. Get keys from `Brdd`: `Brdd_keys = Brdd.map(lambda x: x[0])`. Output has the form: `RDD[(provider, currency)]`
2. Join Ardd and Brdd_keys: `AB = Ardd.join(Brdd_keys)`. Output has the form: `RDD[(provider, (value, currency))]`
3. Map to final form: `newRDD = AB.map(lambda x: ((x[0], x[1][1]), x[1][0]))`. Output now has the form `RDD[((provider, currency), value)]`